# How to get product URL from a `product` input in Shopify Theme

Tags: liquid, shopify-template

I am developing a Shopify theme and in one of the section I am adding a setting that let's the user choose a product from their shop

In the schema I have this

```
  {
     "type": "product",
     "id": "product_order",
     "label": "Product to link"
  }
```

In the HTML I am doing this

```
<a href="{{section.settings.product_order.url}}">Order this product</a>
```

However the `href` is always empty. I tried selecting different products but no use.

outputting `section.settings.product_order` prints the product title.

Am I using the `product` setting input incorrectly?

Answer (score 3):

Hey try the following code it will help you and it works fine in my project.

```
{%- assign product = all_products[section.settings.product_order] -%}
<a href="{{ product.url}}">Order this product</a>
```

or you can also write that code in a single line:

```
<a href="{{ all_products[section.settings.product_order].url}}">Order this product</a>
```